# PHPMailer - How to get "sent from" correctly

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I am trying to make one great form for an project that I'm working on, but I am struggling so much to get "sent from" property correctly. No ideas what is up with this or is it simply meant to be this way ?

Look at parts of my code and then screenshot of GMail with edited "source" to hide actual emails and such.

**Part of config** *(edited to match screenshot data)*

```
$config_mail = array(
    'MAIL_FROM'                 => 'recipient.mail@example.com',
    'MAIL_NAME'                 => 'Company Name',
    'MAIL_SMTP_HOST'            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'MAIL_SMTP_PORT'            => 587,
    'MAIL_SMTP_SECURE'          => 'tls',
    'MAIL_SMTP_AUTH'            => true,
    'MAIL_SMTP_USER'            => 'server.smtp@gmail.com',
    'MAIL_SMTP_PASS'            => '*******'
);
```

**Part of PHPMailer**

```
// Add a "Reply-to" address.
$mail->addReplyTo($form_email, $form_name);
// Set the From and FromName properties
$mail->setFrom($form_email, $form_name);
// Add a "To" address.
$mail->addAddress($config_mail['MAIL_FROM'], $config_mail['MAIL_NAME']);
```

**Screenshot** *(stating issue in explanation below)*
[image: gmail edit screenshot]

**Issue explanation**
You can see on the image that the from is incorrect so I had to use $replyTo, but it still seems like a problem to me. Maybe it must be that way since its being sent from server using SMTP, but I still want to know why is it like that and is it possible to change it?

I believe this line:

```
from: Sender Name <server.smtp@gmail.com>
```

Should be like this, instead:

```
from: Sender Name <sender.mail@example.com>
```

So am I wrong or it must be this way ? I tried to explain my issue in depth, hopefully I will get quality answer to it, because I really don't get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail forces sender to the authenticated user whatever you try to set in whatever programing language you use. This behavior is by design.

Comment: Hmmm, alright if it is like that. Does it mean that if I setup an email of my domain for example: sample@dvL-den.net, that I will actually get correct "from" and not "smtp from" ?

Comment: @dvLden, if your domain authorizes to set a particular "from" (unlike Gmail), that should work correctly.

Comment: It works if either gmail is handling your domain, or if you have authorised individual 'from' addresses.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mail() test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: I don't need PHPMailer example mate